# ASP.NET MVC - Como trabajar con vistas parciales dentro de una vista fuertemente tipada

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

podría indicarme como trabajar en este contexto:

Tengo una vista fuertemente tipada que realiza la búsqueda de unos registros, el botón buscar mediante ajax carga una vista parcial en un div de la vista principal, luego en esta vista parcial selecciono unos check y radios y luego deberá enviar todo el contenido.

La pregunta del millón es, como envío todos los datos en el submit, tanto el de la vista principal como el de la vista parcial? esto lo pregunto ya que al ser fuertemente tipada solo envía una instancia de un modelo y no de dos.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Indica por favor el código de la Vista principal y de la parcial, así como de la llamada Ajax y de la Acción del Controlador donde recibes los datos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes modificar el modelo principal para que tenga una propiedad del mismo tipo del modelo de la vista parcial.

o con Request.Form puedes obtener los valores de los controles html de la vista parcial